# How should I create a tag for Godzilla Against Mechagodzilla, since it's more than 25 characters?

Tags: discussion, tags

I just asked [a question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/73904/12783) about *[Godzilla Against Mechagodzilla](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Godzilla_Against_Mechagodzilla)* (not to be confused with *[Godzilla vs. Mechagodzilla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Godzilla_vs._Mechagodzilla)* or *[Godzilla vs. Mechagodzilla II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Godzilla_vs._Mechagodzilla_II)*). However, I couldn't figure out how to tag the movie.

The full title is more than 25 characters and there are no filler words like "a" or "the". I settled on [godzilla-ag-mechagodzilla](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/godzilla-ag-mechagodzilla) (25 characters), but am not really happy with it since it seems awkward. Using [godzilla-mechagodzilla](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/godzilla-mechagodzilla) sounds like a character tag and will likely lead to confusion with *Godzilla vs. Mechagodzilla*. And [godzilla-against-mecha](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/godzilla-against-mecha) (22 characters) seems to be missing a key word.

So what would be a good tag for this movie?

Comment: Well, there are no legitimate character tags here, so there wouldn't really be any ambguity. But I agree that it might sound less optimal, even if maybe still the best compromise.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson I'm also concerned that [godzilla-mechagodzilla] would be confused with *Godzilla vs. Mechagodzilla*, should someone want to ask a question about that film.

Comment: Oh god, don't tell me that's an actual different movie. That would have been my next suggestion. Might be worth adding that fact into your question.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Yup, and there is also [Godzilla vs. Mechagodzilla II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Godzilla_vs._Mechagodzilla_II). Added that to the question.

Comment: To me [tag:godzilla-against-mecha] sound more legit and less confusing to other films.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the recent [maximum tag length increase to 35 characters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/299490/162011), this whole problem solves itself and I have renamed the tag to [godzilla-against-mechagodzilla](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/godzilla-against-mechagodzilla).